Input lag after switching Input Source
On my Mac, I have 3 different Input Sources and after some time from rebooting, I'm starting to experience input lag when switching between input sources.
Here is a video - I press my shortcut to change the input source (as I see on the menu bar - it's switching immediately) and then I start typing rapidly.
Usually, this bug appears a few days after I restart my computer. For example, this happened today - uptime is 2 days.
For switching language I'm using Karabiner + MLSwitcher. Karabiner just maps Caps Lock to Ctrl+Shift and MLSwicher catches this combo and cycles through my input sources.
I think this is not a problem with Karabiner or MLSwitcher, because the language in the bar menu switches immediately after pressing the caps lock.
The application in which I switch languages also freezes for a moment.
Here is the video: https://cln.sh/MSLcl0mq

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment so I have to post this as an answer — but do you experience the same delay when you use the system switch input source combo Ctrl+Option+Space ("Select next source in input menu" in "Keyboard shortcuts -> Input sources")?

@hym3242 yes, the same delay. But can say after some time, because I've rebooted my Mac)

The problem was with CursorUIViewService - it's not responding in Monitor. Just kill it. Also I hope that this patch will help to prevent this bug - https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/171vtvz/script_disable_the_new_text_insertion_point/

That's nice to know. Though it's not really a patch, it's really just a script that writes a plist for you.
